# protoc command not working with go generate

Tags: go, protoc

I have the following .proto file:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/path/to/package/myPkg.proto
```

with the following first few lines:

```
syntax="proto3";
package myPkg;
option go_package = "github.com/path/to/package";
```

Then I am creating a .go file with the following

```
//go:generate protoc -I $GOPATH/src/github.com/path/to/package --go_out=plugins=grpc:$GOPATH/src myPkg.proto
package someRandomGoPackage
```

The above `protoc` command works perfectly when run from `bash` (a new `myPkg.pb.go` is created under `github.com/path/to/package`), but it does nothing when I run `go generate -x -v -n` except print the command.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is dumb.

the answer is to not use the `-n` flag in the `go generate` command.  that just prints what to execute without actually executing.